# character comparison in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query in sql

```
SELECT SUM(WT.TRANSACTION_QUANTITY * WTA.RATE_OR_AMOUNT)
FROM WIP_TRANSACTION_ACCOUNTS WTA, WIP_TRANSACTIONS WT
WHERE WTA.TRANSACTION_ID = WT.TRANSACTION_ID
   AND WTA.ORGANIZATION_ID = WT.ORGANIZATION_ID
   AND WTA.ACCOUNTING_LINE_TYPE =7
   AND WTA.WIP_ENTITY_ID = 1757481
   AND NVL(wt.ATTRIBUTE1,'-') LIKE '-'
   AND NVL(wt.ATTRIBUTE2,'-') LIKE '-';
```

it return values, but using the same query in procedure with P_productioncard  and P_SHIFT parameters, it return NULLS.

Here is the procedure

```
FUNCTION       get_value3 ( p_wip_entity_id NUMBER
                                , P_productioncard VARCHAR2
                                , P_SHIFT VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER is

    l_total number;

begin

    SELECT SUM(WT.TRANSACTION_QUANTITY* WTA.RATE_OR_AMOUNT) 
    INTO l_total
    FROM WIP_TRANSACTION_ACCOUNTS WTA, WIP_TRANSACTIONS WT
    WHERE WTA.TRANSACTION_ID = WT.TRANSACTION_ID
    AND WTA.ORGANIZATION_ID = WT.ORGANIZATION_ID
    AND WTA.ACCOUNTING_LINE_TYPE =7
    AND WTA.WIP_ENTITY_ID = p_wip_entity_id
    AND NVL(wt.ATTRIBUTE1,'-') LIKE p_productioncard
    AND NVL(wt.ATTRIBUTE2,'-') LIKE P_SHIFT;

    RETURN l_total;
END;
```

In following SQL, I am calling this function.

```
select get_value3 (  1757481, '-', '-') from dual;
```

Comment: (1) The queries are not the same.  (2) You should learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: just removed 1 line, that is because there are some other lines too, but here I think the query should be simple.

Comment: `AND NVL(wt.ATTRIBUTE1,'-') LIKE '-'` looks like a really complicated way of saying `AND wt.ATTRIBUTE1 IS NULL`; is that what you had intended?

Comment: @Boneist - to my eye it looks like the NVL construction means 'wt.ATTRIBUTE1 = '-' OR wt.ATTRIBUTE1 IS NULL`. I prefer this 'expanded' version myself as the NVL makes it tough to interpret.

Comment: Ah yes, good point; I was assuming the hyphen was something that wasn't expected to be a real value in that column.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.  Can you set up a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that we can use to see what your problem is?

Comment: @Boneist NVL(WT.ATTRIBUTE1, '-') = '-'; means if WT.ATTRIBUTE1 is NULL then put '-' and compare with '-'.

Comment: Er, yes, I know. But, if '-' is not an value in wt.attribute, it's the equivalent of saying at.attribute is null.

Comment: Thank you all, the problem is solved by putting the parameter values in local variable and then using in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue, but then you haven't provided any create table or insert statements for us to try and replicate the issue with.

I've done a small test, and it works as expected:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 id, 10 val1, 10 val2, 'a' val3 from dual union all
                     select 1 id, 20 val1, 20 val2, null from dual union all
                     select 2 id, 30 val1, 30 val2, null from dual)
select sum(val1*val2) result1
from   sample_data
where  nvl(val3, '-') like '-'
and    id = 1;

   RESULT1
----------
       400


create or replace function test_fn (p_id in number,
                                    p_val3 in varchar2)
return number
is
  l_total number;
begin
  with sample_data as (select 1 id, 10 val1, 10 val2, 'a' val3 from dual union all
                       select 1 id, 20 val1, 20 val2, null from dual union all
                       select 2 id, 30 val1, 30 val2, null from dual)
  select sum(val1*val2) result
  into   l_total
  from   sample_data
  where  nvl(val3, '-') like p_val3
  and    id = p_id;

  return l_total;
end;
/

select test_fn(1, '-') result2
from   dual;

   RESULT2
----------
       400
```